# insert a datetime variable in a timestamp field

Tags: coldfusion, google-bigquery

I have a problem when I try to insert a date (Now()) in a timestamp declared BigQuery table field.
I code in ColdFusion language. In this language, the function Now() returns a datetime of this format: `{ts '2014-05-05 15:32:06'}`

This is my BigQuery table schema: `Name:string,Date:Timestamp`

This is my code trying to insert a row:

```
<cfset row.set("Name","Alex")>
<cfset row.set("Date", now())>
```

Since the schema in Google BigQuery API does not support date types other than timestamp what should I do to convert the date given by the function now() (in ColdFusion) to be able to insert my row?

Thank you all for your answers, 
if we have to pass a string variable as a second argument for the method set we can also write:

```
    <cfset row.set('Date',mid("#now()#",6,19))>
```

to retreive a string of (yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS)

Comment: Couldn't you just send now() as a query parameter?

Comment: *we can also write* That method is a bit brittle. The proper way to convert date objects to strings is with `date/timeFormat()` as suggested below. Also, nothing to do with your question, but the quotes and `#` signs around `now()` are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use DateFormat function on now() to make it work. As per bigquery doc, format has to be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
So you can do something like

**EDIT**

```
<cfset row.set("Date", DateFormat(now(),"YYYY-MM-DD")&' ' & TimeFormat(now(),"HH:MM:SS"))>
```

Again, as I said in comment too, you will need to format your date/time in proper manner in which it is expected.

Thanks to Leigh for pointing it out about dateformat not displaying date & time in single mask

Comment: That may not cause an error, but `DateFormat` does not support time masks. I have not looked at the API, but if you really *must* use a string, then look into `DateFormat/TimeFormat` for CF9, or [`DateTimeFormat`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateTimeFormat) for CF10.

Comment: Leigh, even I thought so. But I ran it in CF9 and it worked (supported time masks). Idea is OP need to use a proper masking to make date compatible with BigQuery.

Comment: No, it only *seems* to work. Look at the returned time string more closely. The **time value is wrong** The "mm" value in "hh:mm:ss" is actually a month number, not the number of minutes.

Comment: Try using mm instead of MM.

Comment: @N.N. - If you are unfamiliar with it, CF's `DateFormat` mask is case insensitive. So `mm` and `MM` are equivalent. CF 9 and earlier provide a separate function for formatting time, ie `TimeFormat`. For CF10+ you can use `nn` for minutes with `DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: On top of what Leigh said, TimeFormat is "h" case sensitive. "h" or "hh" (leading zero) are 12 hours format while "H" and "HH" are 24 hour format.